# Create image in C#

Tags: c#, image

I have to apply a Fourier Transform on an image. For this, I want to create a new image with the transform. It is possible to create an image pixel by pixel? Or do I have to modify my basic image?

Comment: What image? .net System.Drawing.Image? ImageBox? There are some images. Whatever it might be, it's mose likely less performance intensive if you create it once in the size you want and then redraw if pixel by pixel.

Comment: I was thinking about System.Drawing.Image. So it's better to redraw my first Image ?

Answer (score 13):

Yes, you can do it.

```
public void Draw()
{
    var bitmap = new Bitmap(640, 480);

    for (var x = 0; x < bitmap.Width; x++)
    {
        for (var y = 0; y < bitmap.Height; y++)
        {
            bitmap.SetPixel(x, y, Color.BlueViolet);
        }
   }

   bitmap.Save("m.bmp");
}
```

But it may be slowly, if you want draw big bitmaps.

You can draw in the same way on an existing image. You can get it like this:

`var bitmap = new Bitmap("source.bmp");`

Use this constructor to open images with the following file formats: BMP, GIF, EXIF, JPG, PNG and TIFF.